# Создать класс, реализующий следующий геометрический объект: Цилиндр

Tags: c#

Объявление полей класса должно исчерпывающе характеризовать объект. Класс должен содержать конструктор, деструктор, Set- и Get-методы для каждого поля.
Заранее спасибо за помощь, ибо в ООП не силен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держите

```cs
 public class Shape
    {

       public float Area { get; set; }
       public float Capacity { get; set; }
        //Конструктор
        public Shape(float area,float capacity)
        {
            Area = area;
            Capacity = capacity;
            Console.WriteLine("Object created Area={0}  ,  Capacity={1}",Area,Capacity);
        }
        //Деструктор
        ~Shape()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dispose object...");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо)

Comment: @Илья На здоровье)